# Open a web page and click a button in VB script

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I want to open a webpage in internet explorer and navigate to a page and click on a button in the page  using [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript).
For example

- i I want to open IE and navigate to "http://www.gmail.com",
- wait for the page to load,
- and fill the username and password into the username and password text boxes and hit the **sign in** button using VB script.

This was the only thing i could find (only to open a page in IE ) :

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = WshShell.Run("iexplore.exe www.gmail.com", 1)
```

please help me out.

Comment: Take a look at this. It might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/vbgeneral/thread/4ec55500-56a7-4656-b4dd-1e5871fc9806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
 Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
 IE.Navigate "http://mydomain.com/form.asp" 
 IE.Visible = True 
 Wscript.Sleep 2000 
 IE.Document.All.Item("Item1Id").Value = "1000" 
 IE.Document.All.Item("Item2Id").Value = "1001" 
 IE.Document.All.Item("Item3Id").Value = "Some Text" 
 Call IE.Document.Forms(0).Submit()
```

Comment: but i couldn't navigate further this code..it opened a web page , entered the value in the text box , clicked the submit button and landed on another page. But I tried to take it a  little further. .i tried to navigate from the screen which i landed to another page bu entering some values and clicking on the submit button..but i couldn't..

Comment: I tried like this

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    IE.Navigate "http://www.google.co.in" 
    IE.Visible = True 
    Wscript.Sleep 2000 
    IE.Document.All.Item("lst-ib").Value = "something" 
    Call IE.Document.Forms(0).Submit()
    Wscript.Sleep 2000
    IE.Document.All.Item("lst-ib").Value = "1001" 

here "lst-ib" is the id of the search text box