# How to click a button in web page using VB?

Tags: vb.net, gwt, vbscript

I'm creating a VB script that clicks a button on a webpage. I've seen answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637899/open-a-web-page-and-click-a-button-in-vb-script) where they submit the form. I don't want this since I require to click on the button with a script so that the usual workflow of clicking a button is engaged.

By the way I'm using GWT and SmartClient which makes it a bit more complex as ID's get obfuscated. To overcome this I'm using GWT DEBUG_ID_PREFIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be nice if you gave a sample of a GWT button to getting help from for those who does not familiar with GWT like me. I found a page that contains a GWT button (hope) and wrote something based on that.
 Consider the following code.

```
Sub WaitUntil(varObj)
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop Until Not varObj Is Nothing
    WScript.Sleep 500
End Sub

Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwBasicButton"
    WScript.Sleep 500
    WaitUntil IE.Document 'wait until the document is ready
    WaitUntil IE.Document.getElementById("gwt-debug-cwBasicButton-normal") 'wait until the button is initialized
    Dim theButton
    Set theButton = IE.Document.getElementById("gwt-debug-cwBasicButton-normal")
        theButton.Click
        'theButton.fireEvent "onclick" 'another way
Set IE = Nothing
```