# Using VB Script, how can i click a button of a webpage? Only the name of the button on the page is known

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Using VB Script, how can i click a button of a webpage? Only the name of the button on the page is known. 
For ex:
In the following website, how can i click on the button "Programming" ? 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to click a button in web page using VB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250218/how-to-click-a-button-in-web-page-using-vb)

Answer (score 0):

If you use object spy / Firebug you will notice that "Programming " is not a WebButton but a Link.  To click on "Programming " the following code can be used.

```
Browser("title:=QTP Tutorial").Page("title:=QTP Tutorial").Link("name:=Programming ").Click
```

An example for WebButton is Gamil sign in page where "Sign in" is a WebButton. You can use the following code to click on the WebButton

```
Browser("title:=Gmail").Page("title:=Gmail").WebButton("name:=Sign in").Click
```

where

Browser("title:=Gmail")  /  Browser("title:=QTP Tutorial") :- Identifier for the Browser

Page("title:=Gmail")  /  Page("title:=Gmail")           :- Identifier for the Page

WebButton("name:=Sign in")  /  Link("name:=Programming ")  :- Unique Identifier for the WebButton,  Link, WebElement, WebList etc.

Click                                                      :- Operation to be performed like Click, Set, Select, getROProperty, Highlight etc.